# Laravel HasMany relationship not giving expected result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three table with following columns:

> posts table

- `id`
- `author`
- `title`
- `content`
- `seen`
- `post_img`

> post_category table

- `id`
- `category_id`
- `post_id`

> categories table

- `id`
- `category`

I created `post_category` table to store post catergories. I wanted to get posts that have specific category. And i created my `PostModel` associated with `posts` table like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\AuthorModel;
use App\Models\PostCategoryModel;
use App\Models\CategoryModel;

class PostModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function getAuthor(){
      return $this->hasOne(AuthorModel::class, 'id', 'author');
    }

    public function getCategories(){
      return $this->hasMany(PostCategoryModel::class, 'post_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

After i got the `PostCategoryModel` from calling `getCategories` method, i created `PostCategoryModel` associated with `post_category` table like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\CategoryModel;
use App\Models\PostModel;

class PostCategoryModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'post_category';

    public function getCategory(){
      return $this->hasMany(CategoryModel::class, 'id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function getPosts(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(PostModel::class, 'id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

But here is the problem, when i call `PostModel::getCategories` in my `Controller` method it gives me this error: `Undefined constant App\Models\PostModel::getCategories`. How can i get categories of a post in my case?

```
Laravel version: Laravel Framework 8.22.1
PHP version: PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2021 23:43:33) ( NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't call relation methods like static method cause it needs an instance to check its id and match with other table. You can use something like this:

```
$cats = PostModel::find(1)->getCategories();
```

But it's just an example and in real application you probably use route model binding or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation between post and category, If so then you don't need intermediate model for junction table `post_category` unless you have another specific reason to introduce model for this table.

For many to many relationship you need to adjust your post and category models as

```
class Post extends Model
{
    //.. Other methods

    public function categories(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post_category', 'post_id', 'category_id');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    //.. Other methods

    public function posts(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category', 'category_id','post_id');
    }
}
```

> I wanted to get posts that have specific category

Once you have proper relations in place you can get posts for specific category using [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function (Builder $query) use($category_id) {
           $query->where('id', $category_id);
         })->get();
```

> How can i get categories of a post in my case?

To get categories associated with posts you can eager load them as

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')
                ->whereHas('categories', function (Builder $query) use($category_id) {
                   $query->where('id', $category_id);
                 })->get();
```

Comment: What if a post that has more than one categories? It will have more than one records in the `posts` table, right? If so how do i solve it?

Comment: @YarkinBey Can you update your post and add this use case , from your comment its not clear enough what do you mean by more than one category? using many to many post will many categories and each category can have many posts